# Getting data to automatically come up once having selected a product

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am trying to make a form on access which allows me to select a product from a drop down list and then the details that go with that product such as colour and description automatically come up. Beloe is the coding which I have done on each of the texts boxes which im using. 
Any ideas?

```
Private Sub filterDescriptionTextBox_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub filterProductTextBox_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub sourceGroup_AfterUpdate()
    ApplyDataSource
End Sub

Private Sub filterCategoryComboBox_AfterUpdate()
    PerformFilter
End Sub

Private Sub filterDescriptionTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    PerformFilter
End Sub

Private Sub filterProductTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    PerformFilter
End Sub

Private Sub productTextBox_Click()
    Shortcuts.viewProduct Me.[Colour]
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, Dominique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your control field behind the Text (IE `ListBox.selected.Value`)?

As well is the form itself bound to a Table or View?

1. If you have a Form bound to a Table then assign the Table field names to the appropriate controls but make them dependent to the ListBox selection.
2. If its based on a View, then you will need to remove the Form's Bound source and then in VBA perform the data population to the TextBox but also handle the Updating of information from the selected ListBox and text from TextBox.